# Get pixels matrix from YUV byte array

Tags: java, android, android-camera, yuv

I need to get pixels matrix from **YUV byte[]** array which I obtain from camera preview in **onPreviewFrame** function. I need pixels in form of matrix in order to implement further image processing.
I'm doing this in the following way:

1. byte[] array to YUV image
2. YUV image to JPEG.
3. JPEG to Bitmap.
4. Bitmap to pixels array.
5. Pixels array to pixels matrix.

Is there any optimal way for achieving same results? 
Currently, my implementation is as follow.

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

try {
    final YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21,
            size.width, size.height, null);
    final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath() + "/" + String.valueOf(br) + "out.jpg");
    final FileOutputStream file_o_s = new FileOutputStream(file);
    Thread comp_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                image.compressToJpeg(
                        new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), 40,
                        file_o_s);
                file_o_s.flush();
                file_o_s.close();

                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
                int[] pixels_array = new int[bMap.getHeight()*bMap.getWidth()];
                bMap.getPixels(pixels_array, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());
                int[][] pixels_matrix = new int[bMap.getHeight()][bMap.getWidth()];

                int start = 0;
                for (int r = 0; r < bMap.getHeight(); r++) {
                    int L = Math.min(bMap.getWidth(), pixels_array.length - start);
                    pixels_matrix[r] = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(pixels_array, start, start + L);
                    start += L;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    comp_thread.start();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(tag, e.getMessage());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify that camera preview must provide RGB images

i.e. [Camera.Parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.RGB_565);](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat%28int%29)

Comment: I'm testing my code on Samsung Galaxy S4 which doesn't support RGB_565  so I'm using NV21 format. Moreover, [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat(int)) suggest using it. Hence, If I try with RGB_565  format application stops and Android Monitor shows ''FATAL EXCEPTION''.